# Dynamics 365 Finance Operations Entity Relationships

Tags: odata, axapta, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I'm working in Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations with OData calls. There is a lot of pre-imported information in Customers and ContactPersons. I was wondering if there is any way to relate the two fields. They are connected via party number, but neither defined entity has a navigation property to party number.

My question is it expected that if we want to be able to query Customer entities and be able to expand on their party number, then expand on the contact, are we expected to modify these pre-defined entities by adding navigation properties? Is this even possible?

Comment: You may need to share some code & explain what you are trying to achieve..

Comment: I'm just asking if this is possible at a high level. D365 finance and operations have pre-defined workspaces and entities. One such workspace is "my customers". If you click on each customer you can add a contact to each customer. I'm just wondering is it even possible to query all contacts for a given customer using odata since their are no navigation properties defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be doable (am CRM guy, not AX guy)

Able to browse some [links](http://daxtechies.blogspot.com/2016/02/understanding-address-framework.html?m=1) to understand AX DB schema & for sure X++ odata calls are way [different](https://stoneridgesoftware.com/working-with-the-odata-endpoint-in-dynamics-365-for-operations/). Even the relationships are available & can set the [navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata#setting-navigation-properties-between-odata-entities) between Odata entities.

```
dirPartyTable.RecId == custTable.Party
```

[image]